# Hive csv-serde error

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive

**Hi.
When I run the following script in the console hive:**

```
add /LIBS/Java/csv-serde-1.1.2-0.11.0-all.jar;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS database.table (
    date    string, 
    id  string
)
COMMENT 'Ejem'
row format serde 'com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde'
with serdeproperties ("separatorChar" = ";", "escapeChar" = "@")
TBLPROPERTIES ('serialization.null.format' = '');
```

**The error:**

```
MismatchedTokenException(-1!=300)
        at org.antlr.runtime.BaseRecognizer.recoverFromMismatchedToken(BaseRecognizer.java:617)
        at org.antlr.runtime.BaseRecognizer.match(BaseRecognizer.java:115)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.keyValueProperty(HiveParser.java:33488)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.tablePropertiesList(HiveParser.java:33258)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.tableProperties(HiveParser.java:33121)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.rowFormatSerde(HiveParser.java:32497)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.tableRowFormat(HiveParser.java:32962)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.createTableStatement(HiveParser.java:4916)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.ddlStatement(HiveParser.java:2350)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.execStatement(HiveParser.java:1574)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:1052)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:199)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:166)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:389)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:303)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1067)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1129)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1004)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:994)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:247)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:199)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:410)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:345)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processReader(CliDriver.java:443)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processFile(CliDriver.java:459)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:739)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:677)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:616)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
FAILED: ParseException line 33:41 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting StringLiteral near '=' in specifying key/value property
```

**This error does not occur in HUE, only to run: -f hive scritp.hql
INFO:**
Hue
2.6.1-2041 2
HDP
2.2.0
Hadoop
2.6.0
Pig
0.14.0
Hive-Hcatalog
0.14.0
oozie
4.1.0
ambari
1.7-169
HBase
0.98.4
Knox
0.5.0
Traductor de Google para empresas:Google Translator ToolkitTraductor de sitios webGlobal Market Finder

Comment: try putting serdeproperties in single quotes

Comment: The solution is to change ";" and "@" by their corresponding octal values.
For example to "" would be: "\ 073"